# How are simultaneous discoveries handled in biomedical publishing?

Tags: publications, postdocs, academic-life, science

So my situation goes like this : I happened to land upon a significant discovery in my lab In a very field very hot right now. My  bosses are awesome and we send our findings to a ~20 impact factor journal as a rapid communication. Journal review comes back 3 weeks back, reviews are favorable. 2 of 3 reviewers just commended work and did not  ask anything  and third one asked to show extra proof.  I do some extra experiments for revision of article and we send it back this week. I think we satisfactory answered all reviewers questions.

The day we send it back we hear of  a similar paper published in a  different but very famous  journal by a well known scientist of that field. While his work is much deeper  than our rapid communication in one cancer , ours is more broad and applicable to more cancers than his work (that’s why rapid communication as we had hoped we could build upon the work) We also show a very different mechanism that his lab  didn’t. It’s a question of two different labs landing upon a similar  discovery simultaneously. Now my paper is still under review by that top journal. How will his publication this week affect my chances of getting accepted by this journal? 
Time line is this:

*my article submission: Feb 20 2018
My revision submission : Mar20 2018*

**Similar paper submitted : October 2017
Similar paper gets accepted : Feb 18 2018
Similar paper gets published: Mar 20 2018**

I am pretty sure if he hadn’t published,  our paper would have very likely got accepted because it’s a big discovery. But now that he has, I am feeling all the jitters, nightmares etc. it’s literally  two years of my day and night hard work that has gone in this work. Just super concerned.
I am not a PhD, just an  MD. So I am unaware of how these situations are handled in biomedical scientific publishing.

Comment: Some journals, including top ones, have "scooping protection" that will not reject papers under review if something similar is published in that time. Take a look at your journal's guidelines.

Comment: In physics questions of priority no longer arise because papers are on arXiv before being sent to journals. If you had posted your paper on biorXiv (or another preprint server) before submitting it, this would have proved that you got your results independently of the similar paper. And if the similar paper had been on a preprint server six months ago, you could have taken it into account when writing your paper.

Comment: @SylvainRibault The biorXiv is not nearly as well-read as the arXiv. That doesn't mean it isn't valid to use it, and doesn't mean there aren't some advantages to doing so, it is still quite uncommon in most areas of biology, and it's importance for establishing priority is nothing like in fields like physics.

Comment: @BryanKrause Right. But I wonder, does it happen that someone gets scooped after posting on biorXiv?

Comment: @SylvainRibault I'm sure it happens all the time, yes. It's rarely possible to ever show exactly the same result in biology, so it's more important that a paper be well-reasoned and well-read rather than first, with 'well-read' probably being more important. Since it is not yet commonplace for biologists to monitor the biorXiv, papers there are often not going to be 'well-read' versus other work coming out around the same time in top biology journals.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks for letting me know about these preprint servers. I dont think preprinting is very common in the field of cancer biology or if many good journals are cool with allowing a oreprinted  manuscript . But Inspite of it I have got several abstracts for conferences where I had described our findings.still breathlessly waiting for journals decision on my revision.

Comment: @PoseDoc It was your other commenter who brought it up, not me, but yeah, you would want to check with top journals in your field before going after preprint. In my area of biology it's becoming more popular and more accepted but there are still some stodgier (and often the highest 'tier') journals who consider any prior release to be sufficient to block consideration for publication, including preprint.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to share the happy news that the prestigious journal has accepted my manuscript as it is and the report will be online by coming Friday. My discovery therefore gets published less than 3 weeks after the other lab published theirs. Simultaneous discoveries, I would say!

Thanks